# Devise:: Cannot create user through rake db:seed (failure confirmation_instructions)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

User model has a function

```
def self.createadmin(
User.create(:email => "abc@gmail.com", :password => "123456e", :password_confirmation => "123456e", :terms_of_service => '1')
end
```

In rake db:seed, I have to call User.createadmin

However, this fails

```
ActionView::Template::Error: ActionView::Template::Error
    from /Users/bever/Projects/tr/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_mailer_confirmation_instructions_html_erb___1974818942364630283_2154906860'
```

Then I changed the code in createadmin

```
begin
User.create(:email => "abc@gmail.com", :password => "123456e", :password_confirmation => "123456e", :terms_of_service => '1')
rescue => e
User.create(:email => "abc@gmail.com", :password => "123456e", :password_confirmation => "123456e", :terms_of_service => '1')
end
```

It works! Any clue why this is happening?

Comment: can you post your '/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb' markup?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in your question for the method `def self.createadmin(`?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried seeding from the db/seeds.rb file instead of the model? When you try to do it on the model, devise is probably trying to send the conformation mail.

You should create your admin user on the seeds.rb file like this

```
User.create(:email => "abc@gmail.com", :password => "123456e", :password_confirmation => "123456e", :terms_of_service => '1')
```

Remember that if you are using confirmable module of devise you should add this field to the query.

```
:confirmed_at => Time.now
```

Maybe you should add the confirmation tokens and other fields useful to administrate your admin account via your rails app and not on the console.

PD: Probably if you post more of the error shown and maybe the line in the view I can help you more.

Greetings